# Deleting in NSDocumentDirectory

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I save in `NSDocumentDirectory` this way:

```
NSLog(@"%@", [info objectAtIndex:i]);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains( NSDocumentDirectory,    NSUserDomainMask ,YES );
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *savedImagePath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Images%d.png", i]];

ALAssetRepresentation *rep = [[info objectAtIndex: i] defaultRepresentation];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:[rep fullResolutionImage]];

//----resize the images
image = [self imageByScalingAndCroppingForSize:image toSize:CGSizeMake(256,256*image.size.height/image.size.width)];

NSData *imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
[imageData writeToFile:savedImagePath atomically:YES];
```

I know how to delete all the images in `NSDocumentDirectory`.

But I was wondering on how to delete all of the images with the name of `oneSlotImages`.

Thanks

Comment: Should you be deleting files from the user's document directory without their knowledge and consent?

Comment: Im saving images. then Im thinking of deleting them and reADDing, updating like.

Comment: Well that seems reasonable, however `[NSData writeToFile:atomically:]` will overwrite the file anyway, so there is no need to delete them first.

Comment: cause I have an multiple image picker like, a user selects multiple then it shows in preview, however, when removes one check, still same in preview. so Im thinking of deleting them then re-adding.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this ,just copy this code,your images with name oneSlotImages,will be removed from DocumentDirectory ,its just simple :

```
NSArray *directoryContents =  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject] error:NULL];

    if([directoryContents count] > 0)
    {
        for (NSString *path in directoryContents)
        {
            NSString *fullPath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES)lastObject] stringByAppendingPathComponent:path];

            NSRange r =[fullPath rangeOfString:@"oneSlotImages"];
            if (r.location != NSNotFound || r.length == [@"oneSlotImages" length])
            {
                [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:fullPath error:nil];
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hi how to delete this way in NSCache?

Comment: You can just change `NSDocumentDirectory` to `NSCache`.Did you try this way?

Comment: Yes just replace the single word,as I wrote in above comment.It will work. :)

Comment: and then when I'm loading in NSDocumentDirectory, is the same as in th e NSCache, and I just have to change the path right? Cause i know if I store my images in the NSDocu my app will get rejected.

Comment: Yes exactly,even I had changed it because of same reason.It's perfectly true,go for it.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16006/discussion-between-born-survivor-and-superman)

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at NSFileManager's methods? Maybe something like this called in a loop for all of your images.

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:imagePath error:NULL];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use like,

```
NSArray *dirFiles = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:strDirectoryPath error:nil];
NSArray *zipFiles = [dirFiles filteredArrayUsingPredicate:[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"self CONTAINS[cd] %@", @"oneSlotImages"]];
```

The array `zipFiles` contains the names of all the files we filtered. Thus by appending the filenames with complete path of document directory with in a loop, you can make the full filepath of all the filtered files in the array. Then you can use a loop and call the method of `NSFileManager` object like below

```
[fileManager removeItemAtPath: strGeneratedFilePath error: &err];
```

which removes the itm at path from the directory.

By this way you can filter out the filenames contains `oneSlotImages`. So you can prefer to delete this ones. Hope this helps you.

Comment: then how to delete those zip files?

Comment: what is strDirectoryPath and strGeneratedFilePath

Comment: `strDirectoryPath` directory path is the full path of your Documents Folder and `strGeneratedFilePath` is the full path of the filtered files by appending the file names with the documents directory path.

Answer (score 0):

As this is an old question now and also above answers shows how to delete by image name.What if I want to delete everything from NSDocumentDirectory at one shot, use the below code.

```
// Path to the Documents directory
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
if ([paths count] > 0)
{
  NSError *error = nil;  
  NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

  // Print out the path to verify we are in the right place
  NSString *directory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
  NSLog(@"Directory: %@", directory);

  // For each file in the directory, create full path and delete the file
  for (NSString *file in [fileManager contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:directory error:&error])
  {    
    NSString *filePath = [directory stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSLog(@"File : %@", filePath);

    BOOL fileDeleted = [fileManager removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];

    if (fileDeleted != YES || error != nil)
    {
      // Deal with the error...
    }
  }

}
```